# Chrome switching keyboard symbols @ and double quote

Tags: google-chrome

I have this weird issue where chrome has swapped the @ symbol with the " character, also the hash (shift 3) has been replaced with a £ symbol. This is only happening in chrome my operating system works correctly notepad etc etc, the language in chrome is set to English the operating system is set to English (UK). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

While focused on a text box in chrome, hit alt+shift to swap between keyboard layouts. It had me stumped for ages too. Such a strange feature to put in!

Good luck!

Comment: That was incredibly bizarre. I'm glad the question and answer was posted here. Probably would have taken me forever to figure this out!